# Virtuoso giving wrong result, redirect involved

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have [this query](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia_property%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia_ontology%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20yago%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%20WHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20SELECT%20%3Fschool%2C%20%3Fname%2C%20%3Fsnippet%2C%20%3Furl%2C%20%3Fpageid%2C%20%3Falias_1%2C%20%3Falias_2%2C%20%3Falias_3%0D%0A%09%20%20WHERE%0D%0A%09%20%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20schema%3AEducationalOrganization%20.%20%7D%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7B%20%3Fschool%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20yago%3AEducationalInstitution108276342%20.%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fname%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf%20%3Furl%20.%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20dbpedia_ontology%3AwikiPageID%20%3Fpageid%20.%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20rdfs%3Acomment%20%3Fsnippet%20.%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Fsnippet%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20dbpedia_property%3Aname%20%3Falias_1%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Falias_1%29%2C%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Falias_2%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Falias_2%29%2C%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20dbpedia_ontology%3AwikiPageRedirects%20%3Ftemp%20.%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ftemp%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Falias_3%20.%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Falias_3%29%2C%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fschool%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Fexcluded%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fexcluded%20%3D%20schema%3ALibrary%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fname%29%2C%22en%22%29%20%26%26%20%21BOUND%28%3Fexcluded%29%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20%3Fname%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201%0D%0AOFFSET%200&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpedia_property: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbpedia_ontology: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX yago: <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT * WHERE
{
  {
      SELECT ?school, ?name, ?snippet, ?url, ?pageid, ?alias_1, ?alias_2, ?alias_3
      WHERE
      {
        { ?school rdf:type   schema:EducationalOrganization . }
        UNION
        { ?school rdf:type   yago:EducationalInstitution108276342 . }

        ?school rdfs:label ?name .

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url .
        }

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school dbpedia_ontology:wikiPageID ?pageid .
        }

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school rdfs:comment ?snippet .
          FILTER (langMatches(lang(?snippet),"en"))
        }

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school dbpedia_property:name ?alias_1 .
          FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?alias_1),"en") )
        }

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school foaf:name ?alias_2 .
          FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?alias_2),"en") )
        }

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school dbpedia_ontology:wikiPageRedirects ?temp .
          ?temp rdfs:label ?alias_3 .
          FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?alias_3),"en") )
        }

        OPTIONAL {
          ?school rdf:type ?excluded .
          FILTER (?excluded = schema:Library)
        }

        FILTER ( langMatches(lang(?name),"en") && !BOUND(?excluded) )
    }
    ORDER BY ?name
  }
}
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 0
```

You can see that the result gives the resource

`http://dbpedia.org/resource/"Wesleyan_Methodist_College"`

This will be redirected to

`http://dbpedia.org/page/Southern_Wesleyan_University`

Why doesn't Virtuoso resolve the resource and give the final destination?
Is there a way to instruct it to ignore the redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/resource/` and the `/page/` about the resource are different things.  One has a length in bytes, for example.

A web page is not an `schema:EducationalOrganization`.

If you look up with HTTP the `/resource/`, DBpedia sends back an HTTP 303 which a browser will then follows.  That's your browser's choice.

See the output from:

```
wget --max-redirect 0 -O/dev/null -S http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wesleyan_Methodist_College
```

or

```
curl -v --max-redirs 0 http://dbpedia.org/resource/Wesleyan_Methodist_College
```

Comment: This is correct, but note that the redirect mentioned in the question of probably more about the redirect from Wesleyan Methodist College to Southern Wesleyan University, which probably *is* recorded as a wikiPageRedirects property, and *could* be "followed" in the SPARQL query.